# CSS: selecting the last float <li> on the same horizontal row

Tags: css, css-float

I am using the following CSS for arranging list of boxes:

```
 li {
     display: block;
     float: left;
 }
```

I'd like to carefully tune margins of `<li>` items so that the last item on the row (horizontal span) would get different margins.

Are there any CSS selectors which could target float elements based on their position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could target them using child nth-child selector.

```
ul li:nth-child(2){
    padding: 2px
}
ul li:nth-child(3){
    padding: 7px
}
```

Comment: Very good answer. Why I didn't think this in the first place. However, this works only if the rows and cols are evenly spaced (you know N).

Answer (score 5):

Usually, your best bet is to create a negative right margin on your containing block, e.g.:

```
<ul>
  <li>Stuff Here</li>
  <li>Stuff Here</li>
  <li>Stuff Here</li>
  <li>Stuff Here</li>
  <li>Stuff Here</li>
  <li>Stuff Here</li>
  <li>Stuff Here</li>
</ul>

<style>
 li {
     float: left;
     width: 30%;
     margin-right: 3%;
     }
 ul {
     margin-right: -3%; /* compensate for last float %/
     }


</style>
```

My example is hastily written, but I'd note that **the outer negative margin doesn't have to be the same**. You'll have to fiddle.

Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

In short, no. CSS is applied by the browser in order to render the page. The CSS has no way of knowing the actual position of an element once this rendering is done.

You'll either need to modify your HTML markup so that you can in fact use a CSS selector, or you'll need to use JavaScript which *can* analyze the position of the relevant elements in order to determine which one to modify.

Comment: What about the [`:first-line`](http://jsfiddle.net/tarris/wqjLy3x5/) pseudo-selector?  It seems to know which words are positioned where after rendering, and re-renders appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'margin-left'. If you use margin-right:-3% on the parent container's, and it's width is 100% of the page, you'll get a horizontal scrollbar.